# How do I get CMD to open a .bat file or a folder on my desktop?

Tags: cmd.exe

Can you help me make a `.cmd` file that I can use which will open the `2015` folder on my `Desktop` so I can put it on my taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're using the batch file for is to open the folder, then this is a classic [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info) because no batch file is required for this simple task.

1. Right-click the folder and select *Create shortcut*
2. Right-click the shortcut, select *Properties* and in the **Target** field just add "explorer.exe " *before* the full path to the folder (note that there's a space after explorer.exe)
3. You can also modify the shortcut's name and icon as required (optional)
4. Right-click the shortcut and select *Pin to Taskbar*
5. Now the shortcut itself can be deleted since it's already been pinned

There you have it - a direct shortcut on your taskbar to the folder in question with no batch file required.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I open a folder on my desktop using explorer in a batch file?

The following batch file will open explorer with your deskop folder "2015"

```
@echo off
explorer %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\2015
```

---

#### I can't put batch files on my taskbar though

Yes, you can:

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2. Right click on the short cut and choose `Properties`
3. Change `target` to `cmd.exe /C "path to batchfile"`
4. Drag the shortcut to the taskbar.

It should now be pinnable.

Comment: I can't put batch files on my taskbar though...

Comment: You asked "Can you help me make a cmd file". A `cmd` file **is** a batch file :/

Comment: @Rydog see updated answer.

Comment: (1) `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` should generally be equivalent to `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop` and may be more reliable. (2) [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/306582/150988) describes a slightly longer procedure for pinning `.bat` files directly to the taskbar. In short: rename `foo.bat` to `foo.exe`, pin it, and rename it back.

Comment: @Scott Do you have evidence for the "more reliable"?

Comment: Well, I said "***may*** be" -- but, isn't it possible to put users' home directories in `D:\Users`?

Comment: `%userprofile%` is more reliable, because in older versions of Windows (eg. XP), the user home directory is located in `C:\Documents and Settings` directory

Comment: answer updated again :/

Comment: @David: At the risk of beating a dead horse, see this wacky outlier: [Creating User Account Named 'Con'](http://superuser.com/a/915784/150988).